# How to Add Framework in Xcode 15

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, xcode15

Usually I drag and drop my Framework in Xcode 14 and Later, even in Xcode beta I used to do the same.
But in Xcode 15 when I do the same it is giving me error "No Module Found" when I import my framework

I Tried all the different method present on the internet, Like adding framework search paths in build settings, Link Binary with libraries in build phases, Embed Framework in build phases, Clean build, clearing derived data, None of it works.

Comment: Why not try simple "Add files to {project}" from XCode menu?

Comment: Already tried that @soundflix, Same error

Comment: could you solve this?

Comment: im having the same issue....